Device that helps criminals beat lie detectors also cures criminals
While looking for this story I found an interesting story id question at rec.arts.sf.written

An old Analog story featured a machine that could help you beat a lie
detector.
While under this machine, you concentrate on convincing yourself that
you're not the kind of person who could have done the accused crime.
Just in case the police "go fishing", you also convince yourself that
you're not the kind of person who did that other crime, or crime C
etc. The machine helps you believe that.
In the final paragraph, someone accuses the inventor of helping crime
kingpins get away with murder.
"Have you been watching the murder rate the last two years? The
underworld is rapidly filling with the kind of people who would never
do that kind of crime."

I remember this story too - I'll bet it's from the 1980s.

This is Crisis, 1999 by Fredric Brown.

The story ends as Joad tells Rand that he plans to retire in order to work with Dr. Chappel, who has perfected a method of hypnotizing professional criminals into thinking they are innocent.  The by-product of this is that they are no longer criminals!  Joad convinces Rand to keep it a secret and they drink a toast to the imminent end of professional crime.


Wow.  I was way off on this one - but I confirmed it in my copy of Brown's "From These Ashes."  Thanks!
